# julia Error loading custom modules

Tags: julia

I am trying to load custom modules in julia, but I always get the following error:

```
ERROR: foo not found
in require at loading.jl:47
```

where foo is a the following module:

```
module foo

bar() = "foo"
export bar

end
```

which is located at "/home/.../julia/modules/" and I also added:

```
push!(LOAD_PATH, "/home/.../julia/modules/")
```

to my ~/.juliarc.jl file. What am I missing? Btw, I also reinstalled julia v0.3.10, no effect.

One more thing, if I include the file, I can use the module:

```
> include("../modules/test.jl")
> using foo
> bar()
> "bar"
```

works. But it should not necessary, right?

Comment: I guess your path is something like this `~/.../module` ?  if so, do not use this `~` symbol.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Not it's not. It's the full path "/home/.../modules"

Comment: what's the output after you run `LOAD_PATH` in julia?

Comment: 3-element Array{Union(UTF8String,ASCIIString),1}:
 "/usr/local/share/julia/site/v0.3"                          
 "/usr/share/julia/site/v0.3"                                
 "/home/.../julia/modules/"

Comment: hmm... that's wired. this is my testing result:  `julia> pwd()` =>`"/home/gnimuc"`, and `julia> LOAD_PATH`  =>`"/home/gnimuc/foo/" `, I can run `using foo` without any error.

Comment: the path of `foo.jl` is `"/home/gnimuc/foo/foo.jl"`

Comment: Why 'export bar()'? And not 'export bar'?

Comment: Typo, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: `test.jl`? another typo? I think the module should be named `foo.jl`.

Comment: @Gnimuc: can you post this as an answer? Something like "name the file as the module", so that I can vote it answered. Thanks btw, that was the problem. The files name must be the same as the module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

naming the file as the module is a convention in Julia, especially when using `using` and `import` without including corresponding module definition file.

take a look at the definition of the function [`require`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=reload#Base.require) which is implicitly called by `using` to load packages in the [loading.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/dbe775c128a960382e1734a1ad62c09a19e3b592/base/loading.jl#L232) below.

```
...
...
function find_in_path(name::AbstractString, wd = pwd())
    isabspath(name) && return name
    base = name
    if endswith(name,".jl")
        base = name[1:end-3]
    else
        name = string(base,".jl")
    end
...
...
```

if you run `using foo`, julia will look for `foo.jl` in the `LOAD_PATH`.